# python: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: python, string

I would like to do a huge find and replace using python.

`tot11.txt` is a string (has 600000 items), I want to replace items here from the file `1.txt`.

So for example `tot11.txt` has :

`'alba'`, `'raim'`,

and `1.txt` looks like this :

`'alba':'barba', 'raim':'uva'`.

and as a result i would get `'barba'`, `'uva'`, and so on...

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sort2.py", line 12, in <module>
    txt = replace_all(my_text, dic)
  File "sort2.py", line 4, in replace_all
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Also the script works well if I dont use a text file, just writing the changeable items in a script.

```
import sys

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

my_text= open('tot11.txt', 'r').read()

reps = open('1.txt', 'r').read()

txt = replace_all(my_text, reps)

f = open('results.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`open('1.txt', 'r').read()` returns a string not dict.

```
>>> print file.read.__doc__
read([size]) -> read at most size bytes, returned as a string.
```

If `1.txt` contains:

```
'alba':'barba', 'raim':'uva'
```

then you can use `ast.literal_eval` to get a dict:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> with open("1.txt") as f:
       dic = literal_eval('{' + f.read() +'}')
       print dic
...     
{'alba': 'barba', 'raim': 'uva'}
```

Instead of using `str.replace` you should use `regex`, as `str.replace('alba','barba')` will 
also replace words like `'albaa'`, `'balba'`, etc:

```
import re
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = re.sub(r"'{}'".format(i), "'{}'".format(j), text)
    return text
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the replace_all function is a string, as it came from reps = open('1.txt', 'r').read().... so the calling iteritems() over a string object fails because that function doesn't exist for string objects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use literal_eval.
here's your file:

```
% cat 1.txt 
foo:bar
abc:def
```

And here's the code for reading it into a dictionary. As Ashwini Chaudhary said, you get that error because reading `read()` returns a string. Strings don't have a method called `iteritems`.

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> with open('1.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...             trimmed_line = line.strip()
...             if trimmed_line:
...                     (key, value) = trimmed_line.split(':')
...                     dic[key]=value
... 
>>> dic
{'foo': 'bar', 'abc': 'def'}
```

This of course assumes that you've only got 1 `:` per line in your file.

Comment: can't we do this? ```dic = dict(i.strip().split(':', 1) for i in f  if i and ':' in i)```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get the replacements up in a file somewhere:

```
lookup = {}  # an empty dictionary
with open('replacements.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      if ':' in line:
          bits = line.strip().split(':')
          lookup[bits[0].strip()] = bits[1].strip()
```

Next, read the file you want to replace:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as infile, open('results.txt','w') as out:
    for line in infile:
       words = line.split()  # splits on whitespace
       for word in words:
           # For each word, see if it has a replacement
           # if it does, write the replacement otherwise write the word
           # to the outfile
           out.write(lookup.get(word,word))
```